# Congrats to Zaid for Making 10K

Tags: discussion, congratulations

I just wanted to point out to everyone that Zaid has reached a point milestone! He has garnered 10,000 points! Everyone please take a moment and congratulate him! :D

Answer (score 14):

### Thank you!

I'd like to thank all of you for the compliments - I certainly wasn't expecting a Meta post about me :)

---

### But it shouldn't stop with me

We ***need*** more people with five-digit rep in order to grow this site more and more.

How does one get into five-digits, one might ask. Nothing too complicated:

- ***Stay curious.***

  Do you have a question about repair, maintenance or something vehicle-related? Ask away! (Remember that some questions will be flagged as off-topic).

  Don't have time? Post in the the [Questions Sandbox](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25590/mech-se-questions-sandbox) for later reference :)
- ***Be nice.***

  StackExchange policy demands that. The newcomers need it too. Especially to the newcomers, since chances are that they'll be used to the the old-fashioned PHP BB forums.
- ***Vote on others' answers.***

  Because that is how this site rolls. No rep, no growth, the site stagnates.

  And I don't mean just upvotes; downvotes are just as valuable.

---

### Make a difference; be a legend

This site comes up among top hits on web searches.

***Think about that for a moment.***

Imagine the impact you can make to someone's life by contributing your knowledge here:

- A person whose AC doesn't work in the summer
- That lady who doesn't want to sink her savings into a fuel pump that wasn't the problem to begin with
- That DIY-er who wants to learn the right way to service their carburetor
- The dad who needs to get his daily driver back on the road as soon as possible
- The motorhead who wants to know if a cold air-intake is really the performance mod it's made out to be

This is what makes me tick; the rep is merely a small token of the community's appreciation.

Comment: I know you aren't a rep-whore. This was just my little way of saying thank you for all you do here on the site. I'm hoping we all can continue in presenting others with such kudos in the future. In the mean time, looking forward to seeing you (and bunches of others) hit 20k ;-)

Comment: Usually best and tidy answers given, Love it, Also check for OCD , you seem to have that. Cheers

Comment: "The motorhead who wants to know if a cold air-intake is really the performance mod it's made out to be". Sooo... is it?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing you need to tempt me with data :)

Comment: Well, I've heard of 10hp increase being a normal figure, though I feel quite sceptical about it. In most cars I've seen the taken air is already cold, since the airbox sucks from the fender or some other remote area. So it should ony help in case of a boxless cone filter near the exhaust manifold or something, and even then only to (partially) restore what's lost.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing you know what to do :) just make sure you specify which vehicle/engine you have in mind

Comment: Alright then. Congratulations on the milestone, by the way, your answers are always top notch!

Answer (score 7):

Congrats Zaid!  It seems like only yesterday you were at 9950 points.  You blink, and before you know it, they're all grown up...

Comment: Thank you for your kind words; let's keep up the good work and get more users into five-digits!

Answer (score 6):

Congrats Zaid.  Your mother and I are both very proud of you!  Love your next level answers and attention to detail.  Also, thanks for being a source and let me pest you about everything all the time.  You've been very beneficial in helping me navigate this virtual world.  I appreciate it.  You've certainly earned your 10K with a lot of commitment.  Congrats!

Simply put, **YOU ARE THE MAN!**

Comment: Thank you for your kind words; you're not far behind :)

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations and thanks for your thoughtful answers (which, of course, is why we're here :-)

Comment: Yeah, I seem that I'm late to the party…

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations Zaid!  You don't know me, but I spend a lot of time on this site, and one of the things I like best is how much your community truly cares for each other. The way that you people express that care by voting is an example to all other SE sites!

10K is a huge achievement, and another 10k between January and July is even more impressive! Thanks for all your dedication and great contributions!

Comment: Hey Sue! Just so you realize ... Zaid reached 10k back in January. It *is* an awesome achievement, but he's now over 20k :o) Someone <cough>dlu<cough> jacked this thread out of the past! It's alright though ... I think he was reminding me we still need to be congratulating people on their achievements! Thanks for being here to help us celebrate :-)

Comment: Oooops, I hadn't noticed the date on the original post!  I've updated my answer. It's a privilege to celebrate with you!

Comment: Thank you for being awesome Sue! @JMusser has said a lot of great things about you! :o) You should stick around and play over here a little more ... I'm sure there are a ton of questions you have ;-)

Comment: That's sweet about @J. Musser. He took me under his wing from the very beginning and taught me pretty much everything I know about SE, which is only a tiny bit compared to others. He's also gotten me over humps when I was discouraged or confused, so I didn't give up!

Comment: Truthfully, I have a handicap from a car accident (!) so I can't drive any more, although I'm hoping I will again someday. That's why I can't really contribute here. You guys have a ton of information covered, though, so I learn a lot. When my husband is wondering about things, I frequently find the answers have already been posted.

Comment: I'm glad you feel welcome here, because you are. Lurking is better than trolling, I might add :o) Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the encouragement Sue. Together, we can build an epic site!